# How can I write I loop cycle in R for eliminating columns by indexing inside the name?

Tags: r, loops

I need to eliminate a series of variables, named E1_3, E2_3, ..., E128_3.

I was trying something like this but does not work:

`for(i in 1:128){data_wide$E[i]_3 = NULL}`

Is there anyone who faced a similar problem?

Thanks to all the community for your help.

Riccardo

Comment: `data_new <- data_wide[!grepl("^E\\d*_3", names(data_wide))]`

Comment: What are the other column names? Which one do you want to keep? Which one do you want to eliminate?

Comment: @jogo your regex wil also match column `E_3`, due to the use of `*`, which looks for `0 or more`..... `^E\d{1,}_3` looks for E followed by 1 or more numbers

Comment: @Wimpel then use `+` instead of `*` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column numbers of the variables you want to eliminate, you can use this:

```
# a data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1000, ncol = 100))
for(i in 1:100) {
        df[, i] <- rnorm(100)
}

dim(df)
[1] 1000  100

# Eliminating variables 51 to 100
df[, 51:100] <- NULL

dim(df)
[1] 1000   50
```

Alternatively, you can just subset the variables of interest:

```
# a data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1000, ncol = 100))
for(i in 1:100) {
        df[, i] <- rnorm(100)
}

dim(df)
[1] 1000  100

# Subsetting variables 1 to 50
df <- df[, 1:50]

dim(df)
[1] 1000   50
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved with

```
data = select(data_wide, -ends_with("_3"))
```